# How to change view from listview to gridview on button click

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, gridview, buttonclick

Hi I have used below code to display list view with image thumbnail.

I need to display same content in grid view

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
                    <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">
                        <img src="../../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">
                        <h2 class="ui-li-heading">Broken Bells</h2>
                        <p class="ui-li-desc">Broken Bells</p></a>
                    </div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>
                    <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-hover-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">
                        <img src="../../_assets/img/album-hc.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">
                        <h2 class="ui-li-heading">Warning</h2>
                        <p class="ui-li-desc">Hot Chip</p></a>
                    </div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>
                    <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-last-child ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">
                        <img src="../../_assets/img/album-p.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">
                        <h2 class="ui-li-heading">Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h2>
                        <p class="ui-li-desc">Phoenix</p></a>
                    </div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>
                </ul>
```

I searched in JQeryMobile documentation but didn't find any class to display it in grid manner.

Please let me know how change my list view into a grid on click of button.

Comment: What kind of gridview? jQuery Mobile has no such thing. If you want something customized then show us an image of gridview you want to recreate.

Comment: I want to display in tabular format. like ~3(depending on my screen size) <li> items in each row. Please see the link https://www.google.co.in/search?q=listview+example&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=LBKPU5zgOYy_uAS0zwI&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1310&bih=713#q=listview+and+gridview+example&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=0mR8hB-ZmO8olM%253A%3BqX805QQo9z9vjM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.msdn.microsoft.com%252Fdynimg%252FIC561137.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmsdn.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Flibrary%252Fwindows%252Fapps%252Fxaml%252Fhh780650.aspx%3B410%3B231

Comment: Number of li elements per row should change depending on screen width?

Comment: Please see the image link : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=listview+example&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=LBKPU5zgOYy_uAS0zwI&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1310&bih=713#q=listview+and+gridview+example&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=0mR8hB-ZmO8olM%253A%3BqX805QQo9z9vjM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.msdn.microsoft.com%252Fdynimg%252FIC561137.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmsdn.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Flibrary%252Fwindows%252Fapps%252Fxaml%252Fhh780650.aspx%3B410%3B231

Comment: Have you looked at this demo: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/listview-grid/?

Comment: You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will have to remove the whole un-orderd list and relace its list's content to divs having same width and height. After manipulating the document(DOM) call the `$('#yourTileContainer').trigger('create')`. But the thing is since you are inserting html outside the JQM api components you will have to manually control the tiles' sizes.